# Is it possible to have R Shiny use HTTPS while also using HTTPS for Apache httpd?

Tags: redhat, httpd

Shiny uses port 3838 by default, and I need it to use HTTPS but the main site also needs to use HTTPS. So far I've been proxying the url /shiny/ to port 3838 while leaving the main site on port 443 and using iframes to embed the shiny content into the main page, but this gives a warning because the Shiny content is from a different port/not HTTPS.

Is it possible to have Shiny use HTTPS but also have Apache httpd (the main site) use HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, you just need to bind them to different port numbers OR different IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simply proxy this stuff into the `/shiny` directory and the clients will treat it as a regular subdirectory.

In your Apache vhost config, put something like this:

```
ProxyPass /shiny http://127.0.0.1:3838/
ProxyPassReverse /shiny http://127.0.0.1:3838/
```

Everything under `/shiny` will now be fetched from the shiny server. This assumes that shiny is listening on port 3838 on `localhost`.

To keep things simple, you should turn off HTTPS for shiny though, and let Apache deal with TLS exclusively. As long as you have a secure connection between Apache and shiny, this is perfectly fine.

Comment: That is HTTP traffic. What about websocket protocol that shiny is using for client-server communication?